# Creating an Array From String in Powershell

Tags: python, arrays, string, powershell, split

I am getting a string passed in from Python into my powershell script via a string parameter. That string is a list of files that I need to copy from one machine to another. I use a for each loop to process each file in this list. The only issue that I'm having is I can't figure out how to delimit the list with a comma.

The python that I'm using to call this script looks like this (some variables are removed for security reasons)

```py
fileList = '("\\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_23-Sep-20_00.15.00.txt", "\\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_23-Sep-20_12.15.00.txt", "\\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_24-Sep-20_00.15.00.txt")'

subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', '.\CopyFiles.ps1', '-filelist:', folderPathList, '-computerIP:', computerIP,  '-userName:', userName, '-userPass:', userPass, '-destPath:', destinationPath, '-filepath:', sourcePath])
```

The loop that I'm using in powershell looks like this

```
#Cycles through array copying files over
foreach ($file in $fileList)
```

When I use `foreach($file in -split $filelist)` I am able to delimit my list with whitespace but it will not allow me to delimit by comma. Some of the files that I am copying over may have a space in the name so I need to be able to delimit with a comma instead of whitespace.

I have also tried `foreach ($file in ($fileList -split ',') )` but that only seems to copy over the last file in my array.

Comment: So you are passing a parameter to a PowerShell script. What is the data type of the parameter?

Comment: Is there anything relevant to the question in the body of the foreach loop? if not, get rid of it from the question

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It is a string.

Comment: It's a single string? How is the string delimited? If `,` (not recommended), then you can write `( foreach $fileName in ($myParameter -split ',') ) { ...`

Comment: The help topic about the `-split` operator contains a lot of helpful information: `help about_Split`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I added an example of what the list looks like in the question. The issue with ```foreach ($file in ($fileList -split ',') )``` is that it only copies my last file in the list for some reason.

Comment: Please add a sample command that demonstrates the problem directly to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was with the way I was passing in the list of files with python. I was passing in the values as an array in python. I needed to pass it as a big string. After I passed them in like this

```py
folderPathList = '("\\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_23-Sep-20_00.15.00.txt, \\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_23-Sep-20_12.15.00.txt, \\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_24-Sep-20_00.15.00.txt")'
```

instead of this:

```py
fileList = '("\\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_23-Sep-20_00.15.00.txt", "\\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_23-Sep-20_12.15.00.txt", "\\\\[computerIP]\D$\PI_Backup\pibackup_24-Sep-20_00.15.00.txt")'
```

The split command with the delimiter started working.